# JobParametersValidator.validate() method parameters returns null in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am writing simple helloworld application in spring batch, and I'm trying to validate the JobParameters with custom implementation of JobParametersValidator.

```
public class ParameterValidator implements JobParametersValidator{
    
    @Override
    public void validate(JobParameters parameters) throws JobParametersInvalidException {
        //String parameter = parameters.getParameters().get("outputText");
        System.out.println("jobparameters are ............ " + parameters);
        //System.out.println("parameter is " + parameter);
        
        //if(!StringUtils.hasText(parameter)) {
            throw new JobParametersInvalidException("Parameter is missing.........");
        //}
    }
}
```

But when I tried to Sysout the JobParameters inside the validate method, parameters return null.
Here is my console out.

```
2021-11-26 10:06:32.457  INFO 11912 --- [  restartedMain] com.pack.SpringBatchDemo2Application     : Starting SpringBatchDemo2Application using Java 16.0.2 on DESKTOP-T1L7IA7 with PID 11912 (D:\Workspace\EclipseWorkspaceSpringPractise\SpringBatchDemo2\target\classes started by arepa in D:\Workspace\EclipseWorkspaceSpringPractise\SpringBatchDemo2)
2021-11-26 10:06:32.458  INFO 11912 --- [  restartedMain] com.pack.SpringBatchDemo2Application     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-11-26 10:06:32.536  INFO 11912 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-11-26 10:06:33.575  INFO 11912 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-11-26 10:06:33.784  INFO 11912 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-11-26 10:06:33.920  INFO 11912 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: POSTGRES
2021-11-26 10:06:34.262  INFO 11912 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2021-11-26 10:06:34.484  INFO 11912 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2021-11-26 10:06:34.539  INFO 11912 --- [  restartedMain] com.pack.SpringBatchDemo2Application     : Started SpringBatchDemo2Application in 2.596 seconds (JVM running for 4.056)
2021-11-26 10:06:34.544  INFO 11912 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherApplicationRunner   : Running default command line with: []
jobparameters are ............ {}
2021-11-26 10:06:34.713  INFO 11912 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-11-26 10:06:34.756 ERROR 11912 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

Here is my Job creation code.

```
@Component
public class HelloWorldJob {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    public Step step() {
        Tasklet tasklet = (contribution, chunkContext) -> {
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        };
        
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                    .tasklet(tasklet).build();
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job1").start(step()).validator(new ParameterValidator()).build();
    }
    
}
```

Here is my code for triggering jobs.

```
@Component
public class TriggerJobLauncher {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher launcher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;
    
    
    public void triggerJob() throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, 
                                                            JobRestartException, 
                                                            JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, 
                                                            JobParametersInvalidException {
        JobParameters parameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addParameter("aa", new JobParameter("Hello World")).toJobParameters();
        launcher.run(job, parameters);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: How are you launching your app? Are you sure you are calling `triggerJob`? You seem to be starting the app in a way in which job parameters are not passed in as you expect.

Comment: TriggerJobLauncher launcher = context.getBean(TriggerJobLauncher.class);
launcher.triggerJob(); , this is how I am launching the app